# Integrate LibRocket With SDL And OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, integration, sdl

I been currently involved in a game project and we reach the point we're want to added the GUI for menus and other stuff but the time that we maybe spent developing our own system could cost us a bit of time, and this is a part of the system that we don't want to lose too much time.

So, we're reading about some UI Libraries like GUIchan, CEGUI and recently LibRocket which apparently is very flexible and useful, so my question is if Librocket could be integrate with a project develop in SDL/OpenGL in C++? and if you know where to find information about that, because we're unable to find something like that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

librocket is designed to work with any media libraries. You need to write a renderer that derives from `Rocket::Core::RenderInterface`. If you look in the example, they already provide both opengl and directx implementation of this renderer.

For playing sound, there is no default support, but you can easily implement them using events.

Answer (score 5):

I've [posted some instructions](http://mdqinc.com/blog/2013/01/integrating-librocket-with-sdl-2/) and the code required to integrate libRocket into a SDL 2 based app. As your questions ranks high on Google it may be useful to others looking for the same thing.